# Switching graphical user session in lubuntu using terminal

Tags: linux, user-accounts, lubuntu

How can I switch to a different graphical user session in Lubuntu using the terminal? I am not talking about using the `su` command. What I want is a terminal command that does the same thing as when you click the switch user button in the logout menu. If the command took the users login credentials as parameters that would be even better.

Comment: See answer over on [ubuntu.SE]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/633411/how-can-i-change-user-from-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `dm-tool` can be used to achive the desired effect:

> $ dm-tool switch-to-user $USERNAME